# How to save an image in bitmap format along with rectangle which is drawn on that image

Tags: silverlight, image, silverlight-5.0

I am new to Silverlight 5. I am developing a Silverlight application to capture an image through a webcam and assign that image to an image control.

Now after assigning the image to the image control it allows the user to draw a shape, for example a rectangle.

Now the problem is that when I am trying to save that image, along with rectangle, the rectangle is not saved (only image is saved).

Please let me know the solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

To edit images, it is probably easiest to use the `WriteableBitmap` class. You can create a `WriteableBitmap` instance from any `BitmapSource`.

To then edit the image, you can use the [WriteableBitmap Extensions](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) library, which among other things contain convenience methods for drawing rectangles in the image.

Finally, if you need instructions on how to save the image, take a look for example [here](http://johnpapa.net/saving-snapshots-to-png-in-silverlight-4-and-the-webcam).

Comment: I have downloaded example code. while running that code i got below errors. 1.Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type.2.'System.Windows.Media.CaptureSource' does not contain a definition for 'AsyncCaptureImage' and no extension method 'AsyncCaptureImage' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Media.CaptureSource' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). Please let me know about these errors.

Comment: You need to provide substantially more information and example code, otherwise it is practically impossible to guide you in any direction. Nevertheless, `WriteableBitmap` class is a good (the only?) choice when you want to edit images in Silverlight before saving.

Comment: Sounds like you are missing some libraries?

Comment: After capturing image i have assigned that image which is in bitmap format into Image control.<Canvas Height="165" Name="DrawImageTest" > <Image  Height="165"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="184"/></Canvas>
Placing rectangle on image control is as follows:                   DrawImageTest.Children.Add(rectToDraw);
so now the problem what ever the shape drawn by user it should be saved over the image just like transperent without using WritableBitmapEx dll's.