# UnhandledException while fetching a dll from isolated storage in silverlight5

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I am trying to develop one silverlight app which will save and retrieve a dll from isolated storage.
For example I have downloaded and saved System.Drawing.dll into isolated storage if it not exists in isolated storage. But if it exists in isolated storage, i am trying  fetch that dll from isolated storage and then creating a object of that System.Drawing to draw a rectangle over captured image. But the problem is after fetching that dll it will return the following error.

```
[Window Title]
Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger

[Main Instruction]
An unhandled exception ('Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application 
Code: 4004    
Category: ManagedRuntimeError       
Message: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DependencyAttribute' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'.
at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)
at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg)
at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent)
at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent)
at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, RuntimeType caType)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
at System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(Assembly element, Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
at MS.Internal.XamlSchemaContext.ProcessXmlnsDefinitions(Assembly assembly, String assemblyName)
at MS.Internal.XamlSchemaContext.EnsureManagedAssemblyAttributesLoaded()     
') occurred in iexplore.exe [3892].

The Just-In-Time debugger was launched without necessary security permissions. To debug this process, the Just-In-Time debugger must be run as an Administrator. Would you like to debug this process?

[V] View process details  [Yes, debug iexplore.exe] [No, cancel debugging]

[Expanded Information]
Process Name: C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe
```

Please let me know the solution for this error.

Comment: Silly question, but have you tried debugging this with admin permissions?  You may get more info from the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is not possible to reference a .NET assembly from Silverlight, regardless of whether the DLL is located in isolated storage or not. From a Silverlight application you should only be able to reference Silverlight DLL:s or, if you are using P/Invoke functionality in SL 5, unmanaged DLL:s.

If you want to draw a rectangle in a captured (bitmap) image, you could instead download and reference the third-party library [writablebitmapex](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) and use the one of the rectangle drawing methods from that library. The *writeablebitmapex* library is available for Silverlight and WP7 applications as well as for WPF and Metro applications.

You should be able to do something similar to this:

```
var captImg = new BitmapImage(new Uri("capturedimage.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
var editCaptImg = new WriteableBitmap(captImg);

// Draw rectangle starting at (5,5), 100 px wide, 150 px high and color red
editCaptImg.DrawRectangle(5, 5, 100, 150, Colors.Red);
```

Comment: @skumar I hope this could solve your problem. If this works for you, please consider to mark this as the accepted answer. Also, I suppose this is related to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11220327/how-to-save-an-image-in-bitmap-format-along-with-rectangle-which-is-drawn-on-tha). Did you get to the bottom of that problem as well?